# How to insert related entity in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem with insertint related table in sequelize. I have table name **Client** and **User** which have many-to-many relationship and **User** and **AccessToke**n which is one-to-many relationship.

How can I create **User** and **AccessToken** together at the same time?

I tried:

```js
client
    .createUser(
        {
            username: $param.phone_number,
            password: otp,
            Merchant: {
                name: '',
                freeSpace: '50x13x15',
                extraSpace: '50x13x13',
                extraSpaceFee: '1',
                settlementDate: new Date(),
                balance: 0,
                points: 0,
            },
        },
        {
            include: [db.Merchant],
        }
    )
    .then(result => {
        return res.json(sendOtp(result));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But it's just show this error:

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Merchant is not associated to user_clients!

Comment: The error is clear: table `user_clients` doesn't have a `Merchant` column.

Comment: yeah, but do you have any suggestion on how to create User and AccessToken via Client object?